# Hiding Google Maps API Key From Frontend Within Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api

I need to use a Google Maps JS Library Key for my frontend and currently I've been enqueueing the API via the wp_enqueue_script function but the problem is that my API key is visible on the page in a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;key={MYKEY}"></script>
```

I've been looking for a solution to how I can use this API key without actually showing it on the page as a script. Is there some type of way involving a server that can allow the API key to be used without it being visible?

Comment: [Restrict](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices) your API key.

Comment: I'm aware of key restrictions but I am wondering is there also a way to hide the keys

Comment: You don't need to if your key is properly restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to secure an API key is through a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). Basically, you set up an endpoint on your server that simply tacks on your API key and forwards the request to the third-party API, and forwards the response back to the original caller.

I use Nginx for my reverse proxies. The server block for a reverse proxy might look something like

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;key={MYKEY};
    }
}
```

If you don't intend on securing your reverse proxy endpoint, you might want to reconsider doing the work to hide your key. If anyone can call your endpoint without restriction, they might as well have your API key; either way they get unfettered use of your key.